# Where to check for future bluetooth kernel support

Tags: kernel, bluetooth

I am unable to enable Bluetooth on my system. I am running kernel version: `5.19.0-38-generic` on Ubuntu 22.04LTS; with the following info for my bluetooth/wifi module: [link(USB 0489:e069)](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:0489-e069&page=1#status). It seems to indicate this is not supported by Linux at the time of writing. I am wondering how to track if there is any sort of progress being made to include support for this device in the 6.2 kernel.

Additional requested information:

```
[    0.083001] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.244580] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.253788] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[    2.589070] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x05000500
[    2.589530] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.24 DEC: 2 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    2.589533] amdgpu 0000:0b:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.628019] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.628068] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.628070] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.628073] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.628075] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.628078] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.867270] mt7921e 0000:08:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20221227123243
[    5.046049] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    5.046051] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    5.046054] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.777901] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller I225-V [8086:15f3] (rev 03)
        DeviceName: Intel I225-V LAN
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Ethernet Controller I225-V [1043:87d2]
        Kernel driver in use: igc
        Kernel modules: igc
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0cd]
        Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
        Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

Comment: Yes I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: The 6.2 kernel is currently used by Ubuntu *lunar* which will be 23.04 when released; after release that kernel will become the *edge* kernel of 22.04, which after testing will become the HWE kernel stack prior to the release of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (*I was going to add jammy release schedule, but no date is set yet for 22.04.3, but even then it's available some time before then via install of the -edge kernel*)

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have updated to include output from the command you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this to see if it makes the Bluetooth work.  Secure Boot needs to be disabled, check `mokutil --sb`

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19.git
cd bluetooth-5.19
make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.bak
sudo mv btusb.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.ko
```

Reboot, if it works file a Ubuntu bug against package linux and include results from terminal for `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices | awk '/e069/' RS=`

Info on filing bug report https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011078

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this chipset works with Ubuntu 23.04 with its default 6.2 kernel.

I had the same error when I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a new workstation. The computer has the same chipset as that reported by cogle in their question:

```
Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:0616]
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0cd].
```

My workstation reported the same error:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c03 failed: -110
```

I have since upgraded the system to Ubuntu 23.04 and Bluetooth now works.